# Нет бук для прогерства

Tags: железо

Хочу купить НЕТбук для веб программирования. Думаете стоит или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Маленький экран и низкая производительность не подойдут для удобного обзора кода и какой-нибудь крутой IDE.

Даже если пользоваться простенькой средой разработки, размер экрана имеет огромное значение. Да и компилировать код на слабом железе тоже не из приятных занятий.

Так что, подытоживая, ответ - нет.

Comment: Соглашусь именно с этим ответом.Что-то исправить быстро можно на нетбуке, но программировать на нем - не дай боже.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы и нет? Я свой вообще для всего подряд использую. И Интернет, и программирование игрового движка, и даже некоторые игры пятилетней давности идут нормально. Есть компьютер помощнее, но я им почти не пользуюсь. Только выбирай, чтобы он был не на атоме.

Answer (score 0):

Большинство НЕТБУКОВ на Atome...

Мне кажется, здесь важен комфорт во время работы. Если работаешь с кодом экран может побольше чтобы не пялится в 10 дюймовый экран. Ну и смотря какие задачи будешь на нем решать, если пхп для веба то, точно пойдет.